# Cast to Nullable in ternary operator C# creates new variable?

Tags: c#, casting

Assume that we have exression:

```
int? someValue = SomeCondition ? 1 : (int?)null;
```

so when SomeCondition is false,

```
(int?)null
```

evaluates and will be new instance of int? created at this time for assign to someValue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When SomeCondition is false, the value of the ternary-operator expression will be `null`.

The `(int?)` before the `null` is just casting it (not creating a new object).

The cast is required since the compiler enforces that both possible return values of the expression be of the same type (or convertible to a common type). So in this case, the compiler sees that `int` (the type of the `1`) and `int?` (the casted type of the `null`) are convertible to `(int?)`. Without the cast, the compiler has no way of reconciling `null` and `int` since value types cannot be null, and null has no natural type of its own.

You could also apply the `(int?)` cast to the 1 to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yes, exactly; a "new instance of `int?`" that represents **null** is not a *new* instance at all.  It is the constant value we call `null`.

Comment: We gotta be thankful for implicit casting.... try that in C you'll get the error code that hunted me most back in those days: "Comparison between pointer and integer without a cast".... uuuf that drove me nuts!! XD